# How to count the unique values per date using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-analysis

I am practicing data analytics and I am stuck on one problem.

[TRAINING DATAFRAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkE0o.png)

I group the dataframe by the Date Purchased and set it to unique because I want to count the unique value for each date purchased.

```
training.groupby('DATE PURCHASED')['Account - Store Name'].unique().to_frame()
```

So it looks like this:

[GROUPBY DATE PURCHASED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1kM6.png)

Now that the data has been aggregated, I want to count the items in that column, so I used.split(',').

```
training_groupby['Account - Store Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
```

but I got error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Can someone help me, with how to count the number of unique values per Date Purchased. I've been trying to solve this for almost a week now. I tried to search on Youtube and Google it. But I can't find anything that will help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want?

```
training_groupby["Total Purchased"] = training_groupby["Account - Store Name"].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple aggregations in the same [**`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) clause :

Try this :

```
out = (training
         .groupby(['DATE PURCHASED'])
         .agg(**{
                 'Account - Store Name': ('Account - Store Name', 'unique'),
                 'Items Count': ('Account - Store Name', 'nunique'),
                })
        )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

                                      Account - Store Name  Items Count
DATE PURCHASED                                                         
13/01/2022              [Landmark Makati, Landmark Nuvali]            2
14/01/2022                               [Landmark Nuvali]            1
15/01/2022            [Robinsons Dolores, Landmark Nuvali]            2
16/01/2022      [Robinsons Ilocos Norte, Landmarj Trinoma]            2
19/01/2022                              [Shopwise Alabang]            1
```

Comment: Thanks man, you are a big help. Now I am trying to make it show what account store are unique per date purchased. But instead of compressing it on a single column I want each unique account - store column on a row.
Since I think it will be useful when I try to visualize the dataframe.
I want to have an output like this. If this is possible
https://www.mediafire.com/.../goal_dataframe.xlsx/file

Comment: `Error 404`, the file is no longer available.